# Oracle to MySQL Query Conversion

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, join, left-join

I was working on Oracle to MySQL query conversion when I encountered the following snippet that I'm completely unable to understand:

```
select *
from a, b 
where a.liab_id = b.liability_no(+) 
and NVL (a.cust_id, b.customer_no(+)) = b.customer_no(+);
```

Table a columns: cust_id, liab_id, details

Table b columns: customer_no, liability_no,range

I'd be really grateful if someone can explain the query or convert it to the respective MySQL query.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: So if `a.cust_id` is null then it matches all rows in `b`? Seems odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the legacy Oracle comma join to the ANSI join syntax, you want:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b
       ON (   a.liab_id = b.liability_no
          AND COALESCE( a.cust_id, b.customer_no ) = b.customer_no
          )
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b
       ON (   a.liab_id = b.liability_no
          AND ( a.cust_id = b.customer_no OR a.cust_id IS NULL )
          )
```

*Oracle 18c db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1b7547d800ab0f2780d64b9cb91d15a9)*

*MySQL 8 db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b7547d800ab0f2780d64b9cb91d15a9)*

Answer (score 0):

In both Oracle and MySQL, you should use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  That would be:

```
select *
from a left join
     b 
    on a.liab_id = b.liability_no and
       a.cust_id = b.customer_no;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, I get that part but I'm unable to understand the process going inside nvl with join, i.e. NVL (a.cust_id, b.customer_no(+)) = b.customer_no(+)